# Dragging on x-Axis in fullcalendar dayView

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

i'm currently customizing a jQuery fullcalendar for my needs.
In my calendar, i'm implementing the dayView. Every event has
a property "room_id", which refers to a meeting in a specific room.

In weekView, Events can be dragged between days AND time, and this is quite
the thing i need for dayView, where the different days correspond to a room_id.

I'm currently trying to understand the source, but 5000 lines are quite a lot :D

What i need to know is: How can i manage to drag events horizontally, like in weekView?

I appreciate any suggestions and solutions :)

Comment: For dragging, you need anchors (droppables) where you can drop the events to. In a day view, the time slot is one whole droppable. Maybe if you could split this into many different droppables, you could drag the event there. Just a thought!

Comment: I had a similar idea, but the code was too difficult to alter. Now i just set colCnt from 1 to 7 in all aspects of the view. Now i can drag those events on x and y :) I changed the BuildSkeleton function. Unfortunately, my events move to another day (as DayDelta changes), but its just a matter of time until i figure out how (and where) to change that. Thanks for your thoughts :)

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle example of your problem, so we can view and discuss your code in depth ?